# Current working directory of PyPi package is root user folder? How to make cwd the package's directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypi

I have a custom `PyPi` package. It is installed under `Pyhon\Python38\Lib\site-packages\myCustomPackage`.

In the `__init__` code for `myCustomPackage`, I perform a few different directory operations, which failed to find the correct files and directories which reside in the `Pyhon\Python38\Lib\site-packages\myCustomPackage` folder.

I looked at the output of `os.getcwd()` and it showed the `cwd` to be `C:\Users\TestUser`, which is the root Windows user folder.

I would like the root folder to be the `myCustomPackage` folder.

For example, the file `\myCustomPackage\__init__.py` would contain

```
import os
class myCustomPackage():
    def __init__(self): 
        print(os.getcwd())
```

If I run:

```
from myCustomPackage import myCustomPackage
theInstance = myCustomPackage()
```

The output is:

```
C:\Users\TestUser
```

How can I change that to be `C:\Users\TestUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\myCustomPackage`?

Note : I would want it to be dynamic. No hard coding, in case the python version changes or the Windows user changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directory path of the current module, you can use the built-in `__file__`.

To set the `cwd` to the module directory, use:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path


class myCustomPackage():
    def __init__(self):
        module_directory = Path(__file__).parent
        os.chdir(module_directory)
        print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: Thanks you. For me, the [0] index gave an empty string, ''.

Comment: @geekygeek See updated answer using `__file__`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the following function:

```
import site
import os
import traceback

def changeCWD(self): 
    try: 
        sitePackages = site.getsitepackages()
        site_packages_dir = sitePackages[1]
        top_module_dir = site_packages_dir + os.path.sep + "myCustomPackage"

        os.chdir(top_module_dir)
        return True
    except: 
        self.myLogger.error("An error occurred in changeCWD")
        tb = traceback.format_exc()
        self.myLogger.exception(tb)
        return False
```